# C function error: is it better to abort the function or simply exit the program?

Tags: c, error-handling, error-code

The title says it all. Since C doesn't have exceptions, I'm not exactly sure how to handle errors. I've thought of the advantages and disadvantages of both:

**ABORTING:**
Basically what I mean by this is to return an error code (which will be declared in a .h file, maybe with its own `perror()`-like function) and abort the function, and the obvious advantage is that it helps the user do error-handling, but the disadvantages are:

- If the function is not checked every time after it is executed for an error, and an error does indeed occur, it could cause big problems as the program progresses and the user will have a hard time finding where the issue is coming from.
- Looking through the header file for the error codes can be tough and annoying.
- Error codes may conflict with error codes in other libraries or the builtin C error codes.

**EXIT THE PROGRAM:**
Pretty self-explanatory: as soon as an error is found, print the error to `stderr` and exit. The advantage of this is that if the error message is detailed enough, the user will easily know what is wrong with their code and fix it, but the main disadvantage is that the user will not be able to write any code that could handle a possible error and would instead have to change the code itself (and it becomes a bigger problem when you need to ask for input or something similar, in which there are millions of possible errors that could arise from incorrect input).

Comment: It depends on the requirements of the program. The decision will impact user experience in the best case or system safety in the worst.

Comment: If you are the user and create some document for hours. Then during saving you enter invalid filename. Do you prefer to be prompted with an error message and try again or do you prefer the program to simply terminate? That would be the possible outcome of your decision. You cannot prompt to retry if you just exit the program.

Comment: Yeah, both of these seem to make sense. For the thing I'm currently doing, after reading these comments, I think an error code would probably be the best solution, though I could potentially also see some places where exiting would be better.

Comment: It depends absolutely on the use case. If the faulty input is from a user, you can prompt and try again. If it comes from a file you must issue a warning and either skip it make assumptions. If the program controls external processes you can't just throw in the sponge. What you do, can change during the program development, for example incomplete sections can exit with a catch-all, which needs to be refined later.

Comment: You should classify your errors as fatal and non-fatal. Non-fatal are the ones you can anticipate during normal program run  and can be gracefully handled in a way which allows the program to continue. Fatal ones are the ones which are caused by some abnormal conditions (hardware failure, missing components and such) which make the program not to be able to continue.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This seems to be the best answer, definitely helpful. I'd accept this if it was an answer

Comment: OK, refined the above into an answer.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 You have already done a very good job of listing the pros and cons of your two approaches.  But there's no one right answer:  For different circumstances, you will get different answers depending on how those circumstances play off against the pros and cons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This largely depends on what your program is doing. Some programs such as simple command line utilities will just abort on invalid input for example, without affecting much neither the user experience, nor the system stability. The user will simply correct themselves and rerun. On the other hand, if it is a safety-critical system, such as military, medical or transportation equipment (read autopilot, pacemaker and such) aborting its program will cost human lives. Or as suggested in the comments - a simple word processor. The user might be very unsatisfied if they loose all their work after made some stupid mistake which caused some program error.

So the general approach to writing a robust software would be to classify your errors as fatal and non-fatal. Non-fatal are the ones you can anticipate during normal program run and can be gracefully handled in a way which allows the program to continue. Fatal ones are the ones which are caused by some abnormal conditions (hardware failure, missing components and such) which make the program not to be able to continue.

Depending on the system nature you might want to loosen or tighten the above classification.

Comment: I tend to pass an error condition down through the calling functions until it reaches a level that can do something about it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I prefer this approach too, but sometimes it has to make a very long way down, while it is clear it is fatal on the early stage.

Comment: That is true, but any program that controls something has to terminate in the right way. An interrupt handler can't always record the fault. And when controlling a machine it can't just be left to carry on, but must also be stopped gracefully, it's not just obviously dangerous procedures, for example a factory won't thank you for emptying the glue tank onto the floor. Such things must be designed as fail-safe to be 'robust'.

Comment: I think this answer is not right. Also it's not an opinion. A library function must not abpruptly exit the main program.

Comment: @hek2mgl What is wrong, what is not an option and which library function are you talking about, which will *abpruptly exit the main program* ? Are you sure you correctly  read my answer?

Comment: @hek2mgl MS Windows issues the "blue screen of death" as a last resort.

Comment: Eugene it's a sad fact that rigorous error handling at the level of functionality can at least double the programming task, but at the basic level, obviously it pays dividends directly to the programmer.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, making better things is always harder than making the worse ones :)

Comment: @WeatherVane blue screen is for kernel errors (e.g kernel errors triggered by hardware errors). A user program would not be able to spawn this. Btw similar thing exists on Linux: a kernel panic. (but even here, the panic is raised by the kernel's main() function, not by the individual routine)

Comment: @EugeneSh. To express my concern, I think what you say is right, but you don't address the OPs question (at least how I understand it). The OP is asking what a particular function should do, not what the main program should do. Especially the decision what is fatal and what is not, can't be done by a function, as only the main() function does have this context. Therefore the chain should be: (1) lib function returns error code. (2) calling function (could be main()) decides what to do with the error code and if it is fatal or not and, if it's main(), may exit the program otherwise return error

Answer (score 2):

Return a proper error code from that function. Otherwise it would be hard to use that function in a different context, like a unit test. Also it wouldn't be possible for the calling program to cleanup it's resources or, simply print an error message.

Comment: If this program is an autopilot for a nuclear missile, aborting it might have consequences.

Comment: Medical equipment, self-driving car, lots of cases that aren't "one size fits all"

Comment: After reading comments to my question, I think they each have their own purpose, but error codes would seem better in most cases (I did once see a fatal exit when I made a stupid error in `malloc` though, can't remember what exactly it was).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Do you want a library function of a nuclear missile like `update_display()` to abruptly stop the flight control system?

Comment: @hek2mgl No 
I don't. But looks like you do by saying *Abort with proper error code.*. Proper error code won't help the missile to fly

Comment: It does. The main program will know what happened and could take proper action. In this case the proper action would be to ignore the error probably, as the display isn't needed during flight.

Comment: Well, your edit is changing the meaning of the whole answer to an opposite one, so the discussion above is not valid anymore.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for this. I took the word "aborting" from the question, I should not have done that as you are right, it doesn't make sense here

Comment: I think the best and simplest argument is a localized error message. If the lib function uses `printf(someting)` it will get hard to write a program which is using different libraries and still has consistent output